# React Native ListView Item ZIndex

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement a drag and drop list view item, where I can drag from a listview and drop into another.

The big problem I am facing is the "zIndex" from the ListView children, I can't figure out how to get the child row to stay above the other views when I move that

You Can find the code I made here: https://gist.github.com/zr0n/5f4f1ca6ca371e5a5264a4d2de1ae733

[image]

Please, save my day anyone

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I found an interesting workaround in this repository: https://github.com/deanmcpherson/react-native-drag-drop

It was hard to found, once it is not even a npm module.

It creates a transparent modal and clone the dragging content on it, so it stay above the other views. I needed to make a little fix to use it with TouchableOpacity/TouchableHighlight/TouchableWithoutFeedback and made a pull request: 
https://github.com/deanmcpherson/react-native-drag-drop/pull/3/commits/dd16534b8d5d73ff2c95b92c2649c5a176b42986

If you need a Touchable Draggable and when you are reading this the PR was not approved, use my fork with branch Touchable_Children:
https://github.com/zr0n/react-native-drag-drop/tree/Touchable_Children